# Timestamp formatting in sqlite

Tags: sqlite, datetime-format

I have to format a UNIX timestamp to a human-readable format in SQLite. My Unix date column is named as ERDAT and I want to extract the max date out of that column for which I am using the following :

```
SELECT MAX(strftime('%d - %m  - %Y ', datetime(ERDAT, 'unixepoch'))) as max_date FROM table
```

The table looks like the following:

```
BANFN       BSART   ERDAT      clean_date
0000000000  A6  1528236000000   
0000000000  AB  1546470000000   
0000000000  A6  1505080800000   
0000000000  A6  1505080800000   
0000000000  A6  1507068000000
```

I need to have the clean date column derived from the ERDAT column which is a unix timestamp format and has values in the format  DD:MM:YYYY HH:MM:SS

I am getting null as the output where I should see a date. How should I achieve the desired results?

Comment: `max()` isn't going to play nicely with a date formatted like that, for starters.

Comment: You can also just use `strftime('your format', yourunixtimestamp, 'unixepoch')`. No need for that `datetime()`.

Comment: It still gives me a NULL as an output even if I ignore MAX() for once. i have used the following                                                                                                                           
                                                                                                          
         strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S', ERDAT, 'unixepoch') as date

Comment: Probably means your timestamps aren't in the right format.

Comment: But if I import them in a tool like QLIksense or tableau, it shows me the time in the right format. The data that I am working on is an SAP export.

Comment: You should edit your question to include some sample rows.

Comment: Study https://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html.  Sqlite expects dates as either 1) text in ISO8601 formst, 2) unixepoch as an *integer* value representing seconds since 1970-01-01 UTC, or 3) a floating point that is a Julian Day value.  If you need to use sqlite for any manipulation of dates, they need to be exported from SAP in of those formats, but the default SAP export is likely not in the correct format.  These formats will also require special care for importing into other tools or back into SAP.  Each import and export step must be considered separately.

Comment: @Shawn: added the sample rows as you suggested

Comment: Those numbers are way too large to make sense as unix timestamps. Right now is 1575375027. Compare that to, say, 1507068000000 from your table... that's well out of the range that sqlite accepts.

Comment: if we ignore the last three trailing zeros, would then it make some sense? I can see in my data that these trailing zeros are repetitive. If I ignore them, then I am left with the correct Unix timestamp format. if that's the case, then is there any way to get the clean date?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your Unix timestamps contain milliseconds, so use this:

```
select 
  strftime(
    '%d - %m  - %Y', 
    max(datetime(ERDAT / 1000, 'unixepoch', 'localtime'))
  ) as maxdate
from tablename
```

The format `%d - %m  - %Y` that you want is not comparable. So you must first get the max date and then apply this format.
See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/vnCnLvXCybaoTBtMvdUuoY/1).
Results:

```
| maxdate         |
| --------------- |
| 02 - 01  - 2019 |
```